# Как интегрировать платёжную систему в telegram Bot Payments API?

Tags: telegram, интернет-эквайринг

Интересует опыт интеграции платёжной системы и становлением платёжного провайдера в телеграм. Какие шаги нужно предпринимать после отправки заявки в botfather?

Comment: вы про то как оказаться в этом списке? https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#supported-payment-providers